python is setting two variables to a calculated value at once, where only one variable is being set to that value
I've been debugging a function that I coded to raise a matrix to a power value. I finally fixed other errors I got but when I debugged it, I saw it gave me a strange output, on one line of code it was setting two variables to a value at once where only one variable was stated.
x is the placeholder for the power.
matrix_any represents the matrix that will be used for the calculation.
the function is declared as :
def Power(matrix_any : list[list[int]] = list[list[int]], x : int = int) -> list[list[int]] :

if x >= 2 : 
            
            result : list[list[int]] = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
            process : list[list[str]] = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
            
            for raised in range(1,x) :
                
                if raised == 1 :
                    result = matrix_any
                
                for i in range(0,3) :

                    for r in range(0,3) :

                        substr : int = 0

                        for c in range(0,3) : 

                            substr += matrix_any[i][c] * result[c][r]
                        process[i][r] = substr # problematic line

                result = process
                
            return result

The calculation works but when the line that I highlighted is processed it sets both the result and process variables, with positions [r][c] for row and column, with the value substr. The code works perfectly with a matrix to the power of 2, but with a power of 3 or more the variables get set simultaneously on that line.
I tried declaring both result and process with different values at the beginning so they don't get read as the same thing in memory but it seems that they still do. I just dont know what to do

result = process After this assignment, result is now the exact same object as process.  It does not make a copy.

would it be best to set the values after in a nested for loop so they dont become the same object or would this cause the same issue

You can use deepcopy to get a whole new set of objects, but it's usually better to construct your code so you build a new array from scratch.
